# How to filter multiple rows with explicit values and select a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Selecting Multiple Explicit Rows and Column to then Calculate Mean**

Hi Everyone thank you for taking a look at this question. I'm working with a pokémon data set and looking to select explicit rows and a column to then calculate the mean for that value.

The Columns worked with are `type_1` , `generation` and `total_points`.

The Row values are `Grass` and `1`

`Grass` corresponds to the `type` and `1` to the `generation`.

```py
grass_total_points = pokedex.loc[pokedex.type_1 == 'Grass', ['total_points']].mean()
```

This code above works and returns the total mean for all grass types across all 8 generations but I would like to retrieve them on a generation by generation basis.

```py
gen_1 = pokedex.loc[pokedex['generation'] == '1' & pokedex['type_1'] == 'Grass', ['total_points']].mean()
```

I attempted the code above, with no luck I searched around and cannot find any answers to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeremy, try the `groupby` method:

```
import pandas as pd
pokedex = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['Grass','Grass','Grass','Sand','Sand'],
                        'Generation':[1,2,1,1,1],"TotalPoints":[50,10,20,30,40]})
pokedex.groupby(['Type','Generation'])['TotalPoints'].mean()
```

Should return:

```
Type   Generation
Grass  1             35
       2             10
Sand   1             35
Name: TotalPoints, dtype: int64
```

Comment: EMiller Thank You for the timely response ! It all worked out. I was working with the groupby method but your explanation was great.